# Как изменить описание статуса на странице вконтакте?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Мне нужно изменить текст в статусе на странице вконтакте. Использую следующий код и получаю ошибку...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
        VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);
        Messages messages = vk.messages();

        UserActor userActor = new UserActor(id,"secret");
        try {
            System.out.println(vk.status().set(userActor).text("gdfgdf").groupId(id).executeAsString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
{"error":{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method passed","request_params":[{"key":"method","value":"status.set"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"group_id","value":"id"},{"key":"v","value":"5.131"},{"key":"text","value":"gdfgdf"}]}}
```

Документацию смотрел, но, как я считаю, ошибка не связана с документацией для этого метода.

Что делать?

P.S. вместо id использую нормальный id страницы (на всякий случай предупредил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

Проблема была в том, что у меня не было доступа для метода status.set.
Сгенерировал новый access_token с нужным разрешением и все заработало